# Activate SPI & I2C, deactivate serial console programmatically

Tags: i2c, spi, raspi-config, serial-console

To enable I2C and SPI interfaces and deactivate the serial console, you can use the [`raspi-config`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md) tool which works as expected.

As far as I am informed, for SPI and I2C activation, the tool is just adding the required lines to the `/etc/modules` file. This could be achieved by a very simple script in order to do this programatically. Is there anything else the config tool does when activating SPI or I2C which needs to be taken into account when writing an own activation script?

What does the tool do when deactivating the console on the serial port?

Comment: Who informed you it made changes to /etc/modules?

Comment: @joan: Sorry, I think I got this wrong. I meant `/boot/config.txt` instead of `/etc/modules`. I just had a look at the [`raspi-config` source code](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config) which seems to edit only `/boot/config.txt`. In addition, [eLinux' explanation](https://elinux.org/RPi_raspi-config) states the same.

Comment: Have you looked at the code on GITHUB?  The software is freely available there as a bash script.  The key thing to understand is this is valid at the time you read it - it may change with any release update...

Comment: This is a few years ago, and remains an issue - what is written where when I2C is enabled?would love rasp-config to have command line paramters.